# Change return type to derived type during override

Tags: c#, class, inheritance, encapsulation

I would like to have interace A. Which will allow objects of type A generate other objects of type A.
I need the same behavior for type B. In my application is true that all B are also A. So I would like B to be derived from A.

This is my try:

```
public interface A {
    A method1();
}
public interface B : A {
    overrride B method1();
    void otherMethod();
}
```

Note that override keyword dosn't compile here. The only way to make the project compile is make the interface B look as follows:

```
public interface B : A {
    //A method1(); /* commented out because it is inherired */
    void otherMethod();
}
```

However I would like to promise by interface B, that objects of this type have method to produce other objects of type B.

Implementation of interface B could look like:

```
class Foo : B {
    B metod1();
}
```

Where I want `B metod1()` to be implemantation of `B method1()` from interface B and I also want the same method to be implementation of `A method1()` from interface A. I expect the same behavior in all classes implementing interface B. So I don't want to implement method1 each time twice for both interfaces.

I am doing this in c# with interfaces. But I believe that similar question could be interesting even with classes and possibly also in Java.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way to do this properly is using generics like this:

```
public interface A<T> where T : A<T>
{
    T method1();
}
```

Then `B` looks like this:

```
public interface B : A<B>
{
    void otherMethod();
}
```

And finally, implementing a class would go like this:

```
public class Bravo : B
{
    public B method1() { return null; }
    public void otherMethod() { }
}
```

However, you can use the `new` keyword to shadow a method in an interface, but this isn't a great idea as it makes it harder to reason about your code as it breaks normal inheritance.

Try this:

```
public interface A
{
    A method1();
}

public interface B : A
{
    new B method1();
    void otherMethod();
}

public class Bravo : B
{
    A A.method1()  { return null; }
    public B method1() { return null; }
    public void otherMethod() { }
}
```

Comment: Wow. This is almost what I need. I can have instances of B behaving corectlly. But how can I declare variable of type A<T> where T is A<T> and not it's descendant? The type of this variable would be A<A<A<...>>> nested infinitely many times.

Comment: I liked the original answer before first edit more. I know about new keyword and that is not what I need. I want classes implementing an interface to implement method1 only once!

Comment: Sorry about first comment. I used your first half of your answer. And for cases where I need A without any descendants I created nongeneric `public interface A : A<A> {}` and now everything works as a miracle.

Answer (score -1):

That sure is possible, use the `new` keyword here, not the override and implement the overridden interface explicitly.

Edit:
Adjusted the sample based on your comments. You will still need the explicit interface implementation `IFoo IFoo.GetData() { return GetData(); }`, but this one has no code on its own, since its just calling he implicit implementation `public INewFoo GetData() { return new Foo(); }`.

Here is an example:

```
public interface IFoo
{
    IFoo GetData();
}

public interface INewFoo : IFoo
{
    new INewFoo GetData();
}

public class Foo : INewFoo
{
    IFoo IFoo.GetData() { return GetData(); }
    public INewFoo GetData() { return new Foo(); }
}
```

Comment: I want one method impementing both interfaces. I edited the question to make that clear.